# Filtering checkboxes to show their classes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, filtering

CHECKBOXES:

```
    <div class="categs" id="filters">

                <div class="categhead">
                    <p>Ranking</p>
                </div>
                <div class="categsort">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tagchallenger" value="challenger">
                    <label for="tagchallenger">Challenger</label>
                </div>

                <div class="categsort">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tagmaster" value="master">
                    <label for="tagmaster">Master | Diamond</label>
                </div>
                <div class="categsort">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tagplat" value="plat">
                    <label for="tagplat">Platinum | Gold</label>
                </div>

                <div class="categsort">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="tagsilver" value="silver">
                    <label for="tagsilver">Silver | Bronze</label>
                </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">

                [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.hide-checkbox'), function(element) {
                    element.style.display = 'none';
                });
                var streameach = $('.streampic .row .col-md-4');

                function updateContentVisibility(){
                    var checked = $('#filters :checkbox:checked');
                    if(checked.length){
                        streameach.hide();
                        checked.each(function() {

                            $("." + $(this).val()).show();
                        });

                    } else {
                        streameach.show();
                    }
                }

                $('#filters :checkbox').click(updateContentVisibility);
                updateContentVisibility();


                </script>
```

Basically, this is how it should go:
The page loads  (no checkboxes checked), all classes (tags) should show. When atleast 1 checkbox is checked, every class but the checked classes should hide.
Example: no checkboxes checked -> challenger, master, plat and silver classes should show.
master checked -> master class should show, the others should hide.
master and silver checked -> master AND silver should show, others should hide.


What happens now: When nothing checked, shows all (supposed to happen). When somethings selected, also shows all (not supposed to happen).

Need help thanks!

**KEEP IN MIND: The value of a checkbox reacts on the class with the same name, though the classes are not written like , they're added using JavaScript with .addClass('e.g. challenger'). 
 This might have an impact(?)**

Comment: Create demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem. Many of the selectors in your script don't appear in html shown. If they don't exist when this code runs it won't work. Is script tag before or after these elements in the page?

Comment: @charlietfl Edited the id, was a mistake. Script tag is after, just before the page footer. These selectors do exist, i thought it wasn't necessary to show.

Comment: well how can we assess problem if code doesn't match html. There are still classes that don't exist in your html

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if I understood your question correctly. But if you'd like to hide all other checkboxes(and their labels) when you check a checkbox you can try this:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
$("input:checkbox").parent().not($(this).parent())
    .toggle();
});
```

Basically hiding the divs containing checkboxes. Except the one that was checked.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etgk1hve/)